# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'raw_ratings' , when splitting DataFrame

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I come across this error when running a very simple code to split the data:

`trainSet, testSet = train_test_split(datacf1, test_size=.25)`

My dataframe has 3 columns ['ClientId'], ['Products'],['Ratings']

with datatypes respectively float64, object, float64.

`datacf1.head(5)`
Output:

```
    ClientId      Products    Ratings
0   103823.0      Product_A    5.631
1   501462.0      Product_B    -2.493
2   485961.0      Product_C    -1.154
3   945317.0      Product_D    1.541
4   140623.0      Product_E    3.215
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: please post the output of datacf1.head(5)

Comment: your dataframe looks right, so does the command to split it. somewhere in your code, you are trying to access some DataFrame object and its 'raw_ratings' attribute. Please check if you have anything like df.raw_ratings anywhere in your code. That's where the error is.

Comment: I haven't used anything like df.raw_ratings in my code. I simply created datacf1 from my original, high dimensional, dataset.  But I created the ['Ratings'] column by doing a calculation, could the error come from there?

Comment: quite possible. what does the calculation look like? can you share a code snippet?

Comment: @vincimojamdar that is the code I use to create the rating column:  dfc['Rating'] = dfc.groupby('TradingAccountNumber')['Quantity'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int) / x.astype(int).sum())

Comment: thanks @KilliMandjaro. Would you mind posting the columns of the original dataframe, dfc?

Comment: I have about 40 different columns in my original dataset

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using multiple packages (Sklearn and surprise) with same **train_test_split** name like below and hence one is overriding the other. Remove which is not necessary or rename and that should be good.

`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`

`from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split`